# How to generate object Ids for both local and online storage?

Tags: database, mobile, synchronization

My application has both offline (SQLite) and online (iCloud) storage. See: [Offline First: How Do I Fetch Data?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398618/offline-first-how-do-i-fetch-data)

Now, as stated in my past question above, the application is offline first, and I'm currently following the answer in that question.

**How I fetch data**: In first run (or rather in every appear of the screen), fetch the online data, and sync it with the local data.

**My problem is how to properly generate IDs for both local and online storages.**

In the local storage, I do auto-increment (Int) for the index IDs.

Here's what I'm thinking:

1. When adding a new data, add it to the local storage (in case when internet connection gets off), and then let the (above) event do the syncing thing, see: **How I fetch data**.
2. When adding a new data, add it to local, and then fetch the latest ID from the local storage, and increment it by 1 and use it as the iCloudID, like so:

   `iCloudID = localStorageLastID + 1`

   When saving a new data to SQLite, I can't get the ID (Autoincrement) of the  latest local data. So I do a new query for this.
3. I think this last idea is the best, but will take few more hours *sigh*:

   Make a new column to the local database for a customId say `UUID` `(String)`. And make one too for the online storage. UUID are generated using a `String` class on iOS.

   **UUID's description:**

   > Returns a string created from the UUID, such as
   >   “E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F”

Also, if someone could help me with the proper tags for this question, that would be awesome.

Comment: _**My problem is how to properly generate IDs for both local and online storages.**_ Use GUIDS.

Comment: Basically use UUID / proceed with #3, right?

Comment: Of course, that's the only way to handle _online_ and _offline_ IDs equally well.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks a lot! Perhaps you would consider posting this as an answer.